# extracting the java version from multiple linux servers

Tags: shell

My below script is not giving the correct java version from the remote server, instead prints the version of the source server:

```
    for i in 'cat serverlist.txt'
    do
    ssh $i `java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/"//g'`
    done >>sample.txt
cat sample.txt
```

expected result would like below:

> eg: 1.8.181 (each server would be having a different version, that shud be printed)

Comment: here are examples how to use  ssh with commands: https://zaiste.net/a_few_ways_to_execute_commands_remotely_using_ssh/
Also, pssh (paralel ssh) might be usefull: https://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/how-to-use-pssh-parallel-ssh-program-on-linux-unix/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using back ticks in remote command - single quotes are probably what you're looking for:

```
ssh $i 'java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "version" | cut -d" " -f 3-'
```

Comment: not working , getting the below:
ssh $i `java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "version" | cut -d" " -f 3-|sed 's/"//g'`
WARNING

This is a Proprietary System
You have accessed a Proprietary System

If you are not authorized to use this computer system, you MUST log off now. Unauthorized use of this computer system, including unauthorized attempts or 

ksh: 1.8.0_172: not found

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get my results correctly after trying the below:

> ssh $server >sample.txt 2>&1 `java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/"//g' >>s1.txt` exit; cat s1.txt